# Hash the name of a created folder in PHP?

Tags: php, html, hash

so the below PHP code that I have takes the user's ID and checks to see if that user has a profile folder on the server or not, where all of their profile data will be stored eventually--if the user doesn't already have one, it will automatically make a folder based off of the user's username.

I want to make it so the folder doesn't get named the exact same as the user's profile name. I want to hash it. I'm having difficulty doing that, and was wondering if there is a way to add in a hash function to this code to make the created folder hashed. I'd prefer the sha256 hash algorithm but I'm not sure if that's the best choice for this situation, or if it even matters. P.S.: I've already tried just hashing the variable but obviously I'm doing something wrong here. The code is below:

```
<!-- The following checks if the user already has a profile folder, and if not, it creates one equal to the username of the user -->
<?php
$userID = $_SESSION["username"];

// Define path where file will be uploaded to
//   User ID is set as directory name
$profileFolder = "profiles/$userID";

hash('sha256', $profileFolder);

// Check to see if directory already exists
$exist = is_dir($profileFolder);

// If directory doesn't exist, create directory
if(!$exist) {
mkdir("$profileFolder");
chmod("$profileFolder", 0755);
}
else { echo "<p id='welcome-msg'>Welcome, <p id='userfolder'>$userID</p></p>"; }
?>
```

I already know the code works, at least for the main purpose of checking/creating the user's folder. I just don't want the created folder to be the exact same as the user's username.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Where are you stuck? You say _"but obviously I'm doing something wrong here"_ but then you say _"I already know the code works"_ which makes it very unclear. However, do you really mean to hash the folder name `profiles/` as well?

Comment: The code works to create the folder for the user's profile, but the folder's name is the same as the person's username. I want the folder's name to be hashed.

hash('sha256', $profileFolder); doesn't do anything. It doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't have the desired result. It still just makes a folder called (whatever the username is).

I only want to hash the folder name that is created by the $profileFolder variable. So the directory would look like: profiles/(hashed folder name).

If that makes more sense?

Comment: You need to store the result of `hash('sha256', $profileFolder);` in a variable or it will just discard the generated hash: `$profileFolder = hash('sha256', $profileFolder);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are hashing the whole path, not just the user folder.

```
$profileFolder = hash('sha256', $userID);

$hashed_folder = "profiles/{$profileFolder}" ;

// Check to see if directory already exists
$exist = is_dir($hashed_folder);
```

Comment: I just tried that, you are correct but this solution also hashes the entire path. It's creating a hashed folder in my root directory where the PHP file is, and not inside /profiles/

Comment: If you have a const with the base_path of the project, concat it before the $hashed_folder var

Comment: @user17514845 - Could it be that you still used `$profileFolder` instead of the new `$hashed_folder` when you created the folder?

Comment: Honestly at this point I don't remember, I probably did but it's been a couple days now but what @ManuelGuzman posted here should work for anyone else who may see this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am supposed to reply to my own post to show the solution that worked, but I tried this instead and this is what works, and it does so perfectly, thank you guys:

````
<?php
$userID = $_SESSION["username"];

// Define path where file will be uploaded to
//   User ID is set as directory name

$hashedFolder = hash('sha256', $userID);

$profileFolder = "profiles/$hashedFolder";

// Check to see if directory already exists
$exist = is_dir($profileFolder);

// If directory doesn't exist, create directory
if(!$exist) {
mkdir("$profileFolder");
chmod("$profileFolder", 0755);
}
else { echo "<p id='welcome-msg'>Welcome, <p id='userfolder'>$userID</p></p>"; }
?>```
````

Comment: How is this different from what @ManuelGuzman posted? If their answer actually worked, accept theirs instead.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it must be different somehow. Looks the same to me too besides the names of the variables but for some reason that didn't work. I'll still accept it since it was probably something stupid on my end like a typo I missed